# Obtener para una lista de datos el valor mas reciente de otra lista de detalle en TSQL

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta con la cual obtengo el dato de ultimo registro de un campo de una tabla maestro, respecto a su tabla detalle, el asunto con la consulta es que ya la tabla de maestro y detalle contienen varios cientos de miles de registros y está tardando más de lo esperado.

Ya se generaron los respectivos indices, pero sigue tardando mucho, dado que el recorrido de la consulta evidentemente lo hace por cada registro del maestro.

¿Tendrán algún tip para mejorar el query u otra forma de hacerlo diferente?

Muchas gracias

```
select TM.CampoLLaveMaestro, 
        (select top 1 FechaUltimoRegistro 
           FROM TablaDetalle TD 
          where TD.CampoFKDetalle = TM.CampoLlave1 
       order by FechaUltimoRegistro Desc) UltimoRegistro,
        (select top 1 Costo
           FROM TablaDetalle TD 
          where TD.CampoFKDetalle = TM.CampoLlave1 
       order by FechaUltimoRegistro Desc) UltimoCosto,
  FROM TablaMaestro TM
```

Comment: Entonces... tenías la misma pregunta hace un par de días, decidiste borrarla y luego ponerla de nuevo? ¿Por qué?

Comment: Hola Ariel, gracias, fíjate que un amigo acá del grupo había puesto una respuesta, la cual resolvía parte de la consulta, cuando le expliqué en detalle, me recomendó que debía haber puesto más claramente el problema, se lo expliqué y borró sus respuestas después que hice el ajuste y complementé la pregunta. Me quedé esperando a que entonces plateara otra vez la respuesta creyendo que seguiría haciendo el aporte y al no tener más aportes que respondieran la pregunta, decidí borrarla y hacer el planteamiento completo nuevamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es dificil poder dar una respuesta sin conocer bien el modelo de datos y contar con datos de prueba (y el resultado esperado).

Podrías probar esta query, primero en una subquery "TD" obtengo la FechaUltimoRegistro y el Costo por cada CampoFKDetalle de la tabla TablaDetalle (la última fila según FechaUltimoRegistro de cada CampoFKDetalle); luego hago un `INNER JOIN` (si quieres que también aparezcan los registros que no tienen detalle tendrías que usar `LEFT JOIN`) entre la tabla TablaMaestro y la subquery TD.

```
SELECT TM.CampoLLaveMaestro, TD.UltimoRegistro, TD.UltimoCosto
FROM TablaMaestro TM
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CampoFKDetalle,
                   first_value(FechaUltimoRegistro) OVER (PARTITION BY CampoFKDetalle ORDER BY FechaUltimoRegistro DESC) AS UltimoRegistro, 
                   first_value(Costo) OVER (PARTITION BY CampoFKDetalle ORDER BY FechaUltimoRegistro DESC) AS UltimoCosto
            FROM TablaDetalle) AS TD ON TD.CampoFKDetalle = TM.CampoLlave1;
```

Comment: Excelente amigo. Funcionó perfecto: SELECT TM.IdArticulo, TD.UltimoRegistro, TD.UltimoCosto
FROM Productos TM
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT IdArticulo,
                   first_value(com.FechaRegistro) OVER (PARTITION BY cod.IdArticulo ORDER BY com.FechaRegistro DESC) AS UltimoRegistro, 
                   first_value(cod.Costo) OVER (PARTITION BY cod.IdArticulo ORDER BY cod.IdArticulo DESC) AS UltimoCosto
            FROM DetalleCompras cod inner join MaestroCompras com on cod.IdProveedor = com.IdProveedor and cod.Documento = com.Documento) AS 
   TD ON TD.IdArticulo = TM.IdArticulo

Comment: Me alegro @MarcoAntonioPérez!

Answer (score 0):

Existen diversas formas de hacerlo, pero en este momento no puedo probar cuál sería la más eficiente. En general, usar un DISTINCT y funciones de ordenamiento suelen consumir muchos recursos, por lo tanto dejo otras alternativas.

- La primera permite hacer una sola subconsulta relacionada en vez de tener que repetirla por cada columna.
- La segunda es la forma en la que yo lo haría normalmente.
- La tercera es similar a como se hacía antes de tener disponible las funciones que usan OVER(), aunque usando el formato que permiten las CTEs.

```
    -- Opción 1
    SELECT TM.CampoLLaveMaestro, 
           TD.FechaUltimoRegistro AS UltimoRegistro,
           TD.Costo AS UltimoCosto,
      FROM TablaMaestro TM
      CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 
                        FechaUltimoRegistro,
                        Costo
                    FROM TablaDetalle TD 
                    WHERE TD.CampoFKDetalle = TM.CampoLlave1 
                    ORDER BY FechaUltimoRegistro DESC) TD;

    -- Opción 2
    SELECT TM.CampoLLaveMaestro, 
           TD.FechaUltimoRegistro AS UltimoRegistro,
           TD.Costo AS UltimoCosto,
      FROM TablaMaestro TM
      JOIN ( SELECT 
                FechaUltimoRegistro,
                Costo,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY CampoFKDetalle ORDER BY FechaUltimoRegistro DESC) AS NumFila
            FROM TablaDetalle) TD ON TD.CampoFKDetalle = TM.CampoLlave1
                                 AND TD.NumFila = 1;

    -- Opción 3
    WITH cteUltimaFecha AS(
      SELECT CampoFKDetalle,
                MAX(FechaUltimoRegistro) UltimoRegistro
        FROM TablaDetalle 
        GROUP BY CampoFKDetalle) 
    )
    SELECT TM.CampoLLaveMaestro, 
           TD.FechaUltimoRegistro AS UltimoRegistro,
           TD.Costo AS UltimoCosto,
      FROM TablaMaestro   TM
      JOIN cteUltimaFecha UF ON TD.CampoFKDetalle      = TM.CampoLlave1
      JOIN TablaDetalle   TD ON TD.CampoFKDetalle      = TM.CampoLlave1
                            AND TD.FechaUltimoRegistro = UF.UltimoRegistro;
```